# How to write reverseT without using List?

Tags: haskell, reverse, foldable, representable

I need an alternative to `reverseT` that doesn't use `toList`.
Obviously, this code is incorrect, but demonstrates the idea I was pursuing:

```
reverseF
  :: (Foldable f, Representable f, Num (Rep f))
  => f a -> f a
reverseF f = tabulate $ \ix -> index f $ last - ix
  where last = length f - 1  -- Incorrect; length -> ?
```

Does anyone know what I can replace `length` with, so as to get the last index element offered by `tabulate` when building an `f`?

Comment: With [`partsOf`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:partsOf) you can get `over (partsOf traverse) reverse :: Traversable t => t ~> t` for any `Traversable t`. The `Traversable` constraint also ensures that we preserve the shape of `t`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assume and use `Bounded (Rep f)` and `Enum (Rep f)`, i.e., convert `Rep f` to `Int` with `toEnum`, change indices by some `Int` arithmetic that uses `Int` counterparts of `minBound` and `maxBound` on `Rep f` (or assume `fromEnum minBound == 0`), and finally from `Int` back to `Rep f` with `fromEnum`.

Answer (score 3):

`Representable` does not support `reverse` in general, because infinite fixed-shape structures are representable but not reversible, e. g. streams:

```
{-# language DeriveFunctor, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Distributive
import Data.Functor.Rep

data Stream a = Cons {hd :: a, tl :: Stream a} deriving Functor

instance Distributive Stream where
  distribute fa = Cons (hd <$> fa) (distribute (tl <$> fa))

data Nat = Z | S Nat

instance Representable Stream where
  type Rep Stream = Nat
  tabulate f      = Cons (f Z) (tabulate (f . S))
  index as Z      = hd as
  index as (S n)  = index (tl as) n
```

For generic reversal you need finite `Rep` as in Conal's answer, but I think requiring `Traversable` by itself would be acceptable and probably more efficient than `index` and `tabulate` in most cases. You can reverse using the `State` applicative:

```
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

reverseT :: Traversable t => t a -> t a
reverseT ta =
  evalState (traverse (\_ -> gets head <* modify tail) ta)
            (foldl (flip (:)) [] ta)
```

Comment: Extra challenge: do without partial functions by using a different functor.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution looks like it goes through List as an intermediate state. Is that not the case?

Comment: @dbanas yes. With the `Traversable` solution, you can't do significantly better.

Comment: @dfeuer Solution to extra challenge [here](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/cfc22a19c91100f4c7c350833dd86434).

Comment: Nice! I suspect you really do need such mild shenanigans (plugins or `unsafeCoerce`) for efficiency, but it would be double-extra cool to avoid them somehow.

Comment: One advantage of using `Representable` over `State` is amenability to massively parallel evaluation.